# Python Yaml: Iterating through text values

Tags: python, docker-compose, yaml, pyyaml

I have this docker-compose.yaml file. I want to iterate through parameters that can be customized by a user. Meaning that I'm only interested in Values, specifically text values.

Examples of such values would be:

1. `debug,disable-ssl-client-postgres` found under the `services: callback: environment: SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE:` key
2. `./` found under the `services: callback: build: context:` key
3. `- postgres_volume:/data/postgres` under the `services: postgres: volumes:` key

```
services:
  callback:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./services/callback/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - efgs-fake
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8010:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: debug,disable-ssl-client-postgres
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT: '5432'
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_CALLBACK: ${POSTGRES_CALLBACK_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_USER_CALLBACK: ${POSTGRES_CALLBACK_USER}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_USER_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_USER}
      SSL_CALLBACK_KEYSTORE_PATH: file:/secrets/ssl.p12
      SSL_CALLBACK_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: 123456
      SSL_FEDERATION_TRUSTSTORE_PATH: file:/secrets/contains_efgs_truststore.jks
      SSL_FEDERATION_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: 123456
      FEDERATION_GATEWAY_KEYSTORE_PATH: file:/secrets/ssl.p12
      FEDERATION_GATEWAY_KEYSTORE_PASS: 123456
      FEDERATION_GATEWAY_BASE_URL: https://efgs-fake:8014
      # for local testing: FEDERATION_GATEWAY_BASE_URL: https://host.docker.internal:8014
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose-test-secrets:/secrets
  submission:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./services/submission/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - verification-fake
    ports:
      - "8000:8080"
      - "8006:8081"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: debug,disable-ssl-client-postgres
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT: '5432'
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_SUBMISION: ${POSTGRES_SUBMISSION_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_USER_SUBMISION: ${POSTGRES_SUBMISSION_USER}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_USER_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_USER}
      VERIFICATION_BASE_URL: http://verification-fake:8004
      SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES: DE,FR
      SSL_SUBMISSION_KEYSTORE_PATH: file:/secrets/ssl.p12
      SSL_SUBMISSION_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: 123456
      SSL_VERIFICATION_TRUSTSTORE_PATH: file:/secrets/contains_efgs_truststore.jks
      SSL_VERIFICATION_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: 123456
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose-test-secrets:/secrets
  distribution:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./services/distribution/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
     - postgres
     - objectstore
     - create-bucket
    environment:
      SUPPORTED_COUNTRIES: DE,FR
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: debug,signature-dev,testdata,disable-ssl-client-postgres,local-json-stats
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT: '5432'
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_DISTRIBUTION: ${POSTGRES_DISTRIBUTION_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_USER_DISTRIBUTION: ${POSTGRES_DISTRIBUTION_USER}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_USER_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_USER}
      # Settings for the S3 compatible objectstore
      CWA_OBJECTSTORE_ACCESSKEY: ${OBJECTSTORE_ACCESSKEY}
      CWA_OBJECTSTORE_SECRETKEY: ${OBJECTSTORE_SECRETKEY}
      CWA_OBJECTSTORE_ENDPOINT: http://objectstore
      CWA_OBJECTSTORE_BUCKET: cwa
      CWA_OBJECTSTORE_PORT: 8000
      services.distribution.paths.output: /tmp/distribution
      # Settings for cryptographic artifacts
      VAULT_FILESIGNING_SECRET: ${SECRET_PRIVATE}
      FORCE_UPDATE_KEYFILES: 'false'
      STATISTICS_FILE_ACCESS_KEY_ID: fakeAccessKey
      STATISTICS_FILE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: secretKey
      STATISTICS_FILE_S3_ENDPOINT: https://localhost
      DSC_TRUST_STORE: /secrets/dsc_truststore
      DCC_TRUST_STORE: /secrets/dcc_truststore
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose-test-secrets:/secrets
  download:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./services/download/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8011:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: debug,disable-ssl-server,disable-ssl-client-postgres,disable-ssl-client-verification,disable-ssl-client-verification-verify-hostname,disable-ssl-efgs-verification
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT: '5432'
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_CALLBACK: ${POSTGRES_CALLBACK_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_USER_CALLBACK: ${POSTGRES_CALLBACK_USER}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_USER_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_USER}
      FEDERATION_GATEWAY_KEYSTORE_PATH: file:/secrets/ssl.p12
      FEDERATION_GATEWAY_KEYSTORE_PASS: 123456
      SSL_FEDERATION_TRUSTSTORE_PATH: file:/secrets/contains_efgs_truststore.jks
      SSL_FEDERATION_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: 123456
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose-test-secrets:/secrets
  upload:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./services/upload/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8012:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: disable-ssl-client-postgres, connect-efgs
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_PORT: '5432'
      POSTGRESQL_SERVICE_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRESQL_DATABASE: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRESQL_USER_FLYWAY: ${POSTGRES_FLYWAY_USER}
      VAULT_EFGS_BATCHIGNING_SECRET: ${SECRET_PRIVATE}
      VAULT_EFGS_BATCHIGNING_CERTIFICATE: file:/secrets/efgs_signing_cert.pem
      SSL_FEDERATION_TRUSTSTORE_PATH: file:/secrets/contains_efgs_truststore.jks
      SSL_FEDERATION_TRUSTSTORE_PASSWORD: 123456
      FEDERATION_GATEWAY_KEYSTORE_PATH: file:/secrets/ssl.p12
      FEDERATION_GATEWAY_KEYSTORE_PASS: 123456
    volumes:
      - ./docker-compose-test-secrets:/secrets
  postgres:
    image: postgres:11.5
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
    environment:
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - postgres_volume:/data/postgres
      - ./setup/setup-roles.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1-roles.sql
      - ./local-setup/create-users.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2-users.sql
      - ./local-setup/enable-test-data-docker-compose.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/3-enable-testdata.sql
  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin_container
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    volumes:
       - pgadmin_volume:/root/.pgadmin
    ports:
      - "8002:80"
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: ${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
  objectstore:
    image: "zenko/cloudserver"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - objectstore_volume:/data
    ports:
      - "8003:8000"
    environment:
      ENDPOINT: objectstore
      REMOTE_MANAGEMENT_DISABLE: 1
      SCALITY_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${OBJECTSTORE_ACCESSKEY}
      SCALITY_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${OBJECTSTORE_SECRETKEY}
  create-bucket:
    image: amazon/aws-cli
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${OBJECTSTORE_ACCESSKEY}
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${OBJECTSTORE_SECRETKEY}
    entrypoint: [ "/root/scripts/wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh", "objectstore:8000", "-t", "30", "--" ]
    volumes:
      - ./scripts/wait-for-it:/root/scripts/wait-for-it
    command: aws s3api create-bucket --bucket cwa --endpoint-url http://objectstore:8000 --acl public-read
    depends_on:
      - objectstore
  verification-fake:
    image: roesslerj/cwa-verification-fake:0.0.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8004:8004"
  efgs-fake:
    image: roesslerj/cwa-efgs-fake:0.0.5
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8014:8014"
volumes:
  postgres_volume:
  pgadmin_volume:
  objectstore_volume:
```

Does any existing framework like PyYaml allow me to print/iterate through values in such a way without specifying the keys? Is it possible with a Python list that PyYaml generates?

Motivation:
The idea is to print/count only the parameters that can be modified by a user. With a successful implementation I want to be able to say
"X parameters can be modified in this `docker-compose.yaml`" to then compare with other `docker-compose.yaml` files

EDIT:

Unfortunately simply iterating through keys doesn't work, because keys are nested.

```
    for key,value in data.items():
        print(key, " : ", value)
```

simply prints out:

```
version  :  3
services  :  {'callback': {'build': {'context': './', 'dockerfile': './se...
volumes  :  {'postgres_volume': None, 'pgadmin_volume': None, 'objectstore_volume': None}
```

The key `services` contains further keys, such as `callback`, `submission`, etc. When I iterate over keys in the dictionary generated from my `.yaml`, I only can print three "root" keys (`version`, `services`, `volumes`) and their values which are child trees. It doesn't deliver the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: You give examples but you don't specify what the criteria „can be customized by a user“ means. How can the code determine that `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` can be customized, but `SSL_CALLBACK_KEYSTORE_PATH` cannot?

Comment: @tevemadar : Unfortunately it doesn't, because keys are nested. The key `services` contains further keys, such as `callback`, `submission`, etc. When I iterate over keys in the dictionary generated from my `.yaml`, I only can print three "root" keys (`version`, `services`, `volumes`) and their values which are child trees. It doesn't deliver the result I'm looking for.

Comment: @flyx There is no criteria per se, I simply want to parse only keys that have specific text values, wheres keys that contain further keys (like `callback:`) should be ignored. I was imagining that I can check, what kind of Value a key has, and that I could check if it's simply a text value or a further key. I understand that in itself it's all just string values, but I was imagining that it was possible. 

I was able to do it with an xml document by parsing the text values from the so-called nodes. The idea was the same here, although the datatype seems a bit more restrictive in this regard.

Comment: *Unfortunately simply iterating through keys doesn't work, because keys are nested* - so, if you're aware of looping through keys, the next step is recursion. Inside the loop you can `if type(value) == dict:`, and then go further inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `yaml.parse` to iterate over YAML events that are generated from the input. You can then filter out mapping keys, which are usually `ScalarEvent`s, and output the other scalar events. If you need it, you can also track the path to the value.

This generator function implements such iteration; mind that it simplifies a few things, for example it can't process aliases or complex mapping keys:

```py
import yaml, sys, re
from yaml import ScalarEvent, SequenceStartEvent, SequenceEndEvent, MappingStartEvent, MappingEndEvent

def yaml_values(data):
    path = []
    state = []
    for event in yaml.parse(data):
      if isinstance(event, ScalarEvent):
        if state[-1] == "MapKey":
          path.append(event.value)
        else:
          yield (path, event.value)
      elif isinstance(event, SequenceStartEvent):
        state.append("Seq")
        path.append(0)
        continue
      elif isinstance(event, MappingStartEvent):
        state.append("MapKey")
        continue
      elif isinstance(event, SequenceEndEvent):
        state.pop()
        path.pop()
      elif isinstance(event, MappingEndEvent):
        state.pop()
      if len(state) > 0:
        if state[-1] == "MapKey":
          state[-1] = "MapVal"
        elif state[-1] == "MapVal":
          state[-1] = "MapKey"
          path.pop()
        elif state[-1] == "Seq":
          path[-1] += 1
```

Usage:

```py
input = """
services:
  callback:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./services/callback/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - efgs-fake
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8010:8080"
"""

for (path, value) in yaml_values(input):
    print(path, value)
```

Output:

```
['services', 'callback', 'build', 'context'] ./
['services', 'callback', 'build', 'dockerfile'] ./services/callback/Dockerfile
['services', 'callback', 'depends_on', 0] postgres
['services', 'callback', 'depends_on', 1] efgs-fake
['services', 'callback', 'restart'] unless-stopped
['services', 'callback', 'ports', 0] 8010:8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach for the case when you *want* YAML to load everything before iterating. This solution is more general since it applies to any dict/list based nested structure, regardless of whether it was loaded from YAML.

This approach is a bit slower, which should be neglectible in a typical Python application. You will get values according to YAML type guessing, so `true` will be a bool, `42` will be `int` etc., while with the other approach you'll get every value as string.

```py
import yaml, functools

def gen_values(path, data):
  if isinstance(data, list):
    return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + gen_values(path + [b[0]], b[1]), enumerate(data), [])
  elif isinstance(data, dict):
    return functools.reduce(lambda a, b: a + gen_values(path + [b[0]], b[1]), data.items(), [])
  else:
    return [(path, data)]

def yaml_values(data):
    return gen_values([], yaml.safe_load(data))
```

Usage identical to the other solution:

```py
input = """
services:
  callback:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./services/callback/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - efgs-fake
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8010:8080"
"""

for (path, value) in yaml_values(input):
    print(path, value)
```

Output:

```
['services', 'callback', 'build', 'context'] ./
['services', 'callback', 'build', 'dockerfile'] ./services/callback/Dockerfile
['services', 'callback', 'depends_on', 0] postgres
['services', 'callback', 'depends_on', 1] efgs-fake
['services', 'callback', 'restart'] unless-stopped
['services', 'callback', 'ports', 0] 8010:8080
```